# tables and spacing

Tags: html

I have created a couple of tables. now i need both tables to be next to each other and not one table on top of each other. how can i position the second table next to the first one (to the right) but with sufficient space in between?

this is some code of my second table:

```
<table>
<h3>Personaldaten</h3>
<tr>
    <td>Externe Referenz:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
       <input class="LargeText" type="text" style="width: 150%">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Titel:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input class="LargeText" type="text" style="width: 150%">
    </td>
</tr>
```

above are 2 entities from the first table, how do i proceed like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a wrapper around the tables and use float:left;

```
//margin: top right bottom left
<div style="width:500px; margin: 30px 0px 0px 320px">
    <table style="width:240px; float:left; margin-right:20px;">
    </table>
    <table style="width:240px; float:left;">
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why set both of their floats to left? Why not float one left, one right? Or one left, and the other not at all?

Comment: Sure, you can do all what you wrote.

Comment: how do i then define the margin from top ?

Comment: this is my second table now:      <table style="width:240px; float:center; margin-left:320px,">

     
  <h3>Kenntnisse</h3>
     
    <tr>
     <td>Schwerpunkte:</td>
     <td><textarea cols="35", rows=4></textarea></td>
    </tr>

Comment: define margin left and top in the div and only the gap between both tables in the table itself. (Updated my code)

Answer (score 0):

get rid of your absolute positioning if you don't really need it and use CSS like

```
table{
float:left;
margin:0px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices really.

If you're happy creating your layout with tables, then put both of your tables within another table. i.e.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>{ table 1 stuff }</table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>{table 2 stuff }</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or you can start looking into '[float](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/&ei=JLb6T4-hA4Kz0QXSlYHQAw&usg=AFQjCNHmuqofeBKJpUpmAt7wW42MpmJE0A)'ing your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table with 1 row and 2 columns and place your first table inside the first column and your second table inside the second column.That way both tables can be displayed side by side

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would surround your tables in a `div` layer, specifying the width and height of the `div` layer to force the tables next to each other.

For example:

```
<div id="tablecontainer">
<table id="lefttable"></table>
<table id="righttable"></table>
</div>
```

And in the CSS:

```
table
{
margin: 5px;
}

#lefttable
{
float: left;
}
```

Obviously, this code isn't going to be *exactly* what OP wants, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

**#1:**

```
table {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left
}
```

**#2:**

```
table {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block
}
```

See http://shaquin.tk/experiments/tables2.html and http://shaquin.tk/experiments/tables3.html.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the syntax and styling. A `table` element cannot have an `h3` child. Either put the `h3` inside a cell (which is inside a `tr`), or turn it to a `caption`. Don’t set a width of 150%, as this would make the a cell occupy 150% of the width of the available space. The width of an input field set is best set in characters, using the `size` attribute in HTML.

Then you can float the tables in CSS as suggested in other answers, or by using `align=left` in `table` tags. To create horizontal spacing between the tables, you can set e.g. `margin-right` on the first table.

Note that for usability and accessibility, forms should normally be presented so that there is one input item with its label on one line, so that filling out the form proceeds vertically in a simple manner. So you might be solving the wrong problem.